# Why does `firebase serve` error with `HTTP Error: 400, Request contains an invalid argument`?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am trying to test new functions locally.

Project file structure is:

```
App/
   typescript_functions/
   flutter_web_app/
   .firebaserc
   firebase.json
   firestore.indexes.json
   firestore.rules
```

Running:
`firebase serve --only functions` from either App/ or functions/

returns:
`Error: HTTP Error: 400, Request contains an invalid argument.`

Is this some kind of authentication error?

I downgraded from `node@12` to `node@8`

```
node -v
v8.16.2
```

```
npm -v
6.4.1
```

```
firebase --version
7.6.1
```

I have made sure that my `.bash_profile` and `.zshrc` paths to `node` and `npm` are correct. I can post those files if it helps.

I've run `firebase logout` and then `firebase login` with no problems. I can access `https://console.firebase.google.com` with no problems.

I've quit terminal and reopened it after downgrading Node.

I've shut down and restarted my computer.

Project file structure is:

```
App/
   typescript_functions/
   flutter_web_app/
   .firebaserc
   firebase.json
   firestore.indexes.json
   firestore.rules
```

In App/
firebase.json:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
    ]
  }
}
```

In functions/
package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/puppeteer": "^1.20.2",
    "algoliasearch": "^3.35.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.1.0",
    "puppeteer": "^1.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/algoliasearch": "^3.34.3",
    "@types/dotenv": "^6.1.1",
    "jest-puppeteer": "^4.3.0",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Running `firebase serve --only functions --debug`
Returns:

```
[2019-10-23T02:06:29.461Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[2019-10-23T02:06:29.464Z] Command:       /usr/local/Cellar/node@8/8.16.2/bin/node /usr/local/bin/firebase serve --only functions --debug
[2019-10-23T02:06:29.465Z] CLI Version:   7.6.1
[2019-10-23T02:06:29.465Z] Platform:      darwin
[2019-10-23T02:06:29.465Z] Node Version:  v8.16.2
[2019-10-23T02:06:29.465Z] Time:          Tue Oct 22 2019 19:06:29 GMT-0700 (PDT)
[2019-10-23T02:06:29.465Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[2019-10-23T02:06:29.466Z] 
[2019-10-23T02:06:29.473Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[2019-10-23T02:06:29.474Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[2019-10-23T02:06:29.474Z] [iam] checking project [PROJECT] for permissions ["firebase.projects.get"]
[2019-10-23T02:06:29.476Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[PROJECT]:testIamPermissions  
 permissions=[firebase.projects.get]
[2019-10-23T02:06:29.609Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 400 vary=X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding, content-type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, date=Wed, 23 Oct 2019 02:06:29 GMT, server=ESF, cache-control=private, x-xss-protection=0, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN, x-content-type-options=nosniff, server-timing=gfet4t7; dur=59, alt-svc=quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000, accept-ranges=none, transfer-encoding=chunked
[2019-10-23T02:06:29.610Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY code=400, message=Request contains an invalid argument., status=INVALID_ARGUMENT

Error: HTTP Error: 400, Request contains an invalid argument.
[2019-10-23T02:06:29.673Z] Error Context: {
  "body": {
    "error": {
      "code": 400,
      "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
      "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "statusCode": 400,
    "body": {
      "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
      }
    },
    "headers": {
      "vary": "X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "date": "Wed, 23 Oct 2019 02:06:29 GMT",
      "server": "ESF",
      "cache-control": "private",
      "x-xss-protection": "0",
      "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
      "server-timing": "gfet4t7; dur=59",
      "alt-svc": "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\",h3-Q048=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000",
      "accept-ranges": "none",
      "transfer-encoding": "chunked"
    },
    "request": {
      "uri": {
        "protocol": "https:",
        "slashes": true,
        "auth": null,
        "host": "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com",
        "port": 443,
        "hostname": "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com",
        "hash": null,
        "search": null,
        "query": null,
        "pathname": "/v1/projects/[PROJECT]:testIamPermissions",
        "path": "/v1/projects/[PROJECT]:testIamPermissions",
        "href": "https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[PROJECT]:testIamPermissions"
      },
      "method": "POST"
    }
  }
}
```

I am expecting to be able to call functions locally with http at localhost:5000. For example:

```
curl "http://localhost:5000/project-name/us-central1/runMyFunction?someDocumentId=some-someDocumentId-hash&anotherDocumentId=some-anotherDocumentId-hash"
```

Instead I get `Error: HTTP Error: 400, Request contains an invalid argument.`

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the code you're trying to run.

Comment: @DougStevenson, I have been failing on trying to create an MCVE all morning. But an interesting thing that I've discovered along the way is that GCloud and/or Cloud IAM is somehow using the first word of the project name, not the project ID. I'm trying to figure out why that's happening.

I created another project that works as expected, including GCloud and Cloud IAM.

Answer (score 3):

Running `firebase serve --only functions --debug` showed that the first word of the project name was being used to check permissions, instead of the project ID.

The solution in my case was to run `gcloud components update`, `firebase logout`, `firebase login`, then `firebase use [projectID]`.

I don't know that logging out and in was necessary, but I was trying to cover all bases.